# Does Grails have anything like acts_as_tree in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, tree, persistence

I am just getting into Grails having had some experience with Rails, and I am looking at creating an app where I have to primarily persist tree structures (and query them as well).

Rails has several very useful `acts_as` helpers for representing domain objects as different data structures, such as `acts_as_tree`. From my initial reading it doesn't appear that Grails has anything like this.

Is there any support for this, or are there Grails plugins that offer the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page seems to say you just need to define the relationships within the model :

http://markmail.org/message/ukhxqs6i2j3tgmpr#query:+page:1+mid:5g5q7xz7qsq4fn7q+state:results